# HTTP(S) Load Balancing for Kubernetes / Docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a restfull service behind self signed cert thru NGINX in google cloud kubernetes infrastructure.
Kubernetes service loader exposes 443 and routes the traffic those containers. All is working just fine as expected other than asking internal clients to ignore the self sign cert warning!
It is time for to move to CA cert thus only option as far as I see is https loader but I couldnt figure out how we can reroute the traffic to service loader or directly to pods as service loader(http loader)

Any help apprecaited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Update Firewall Rules for:

   ```
   IP: 130.211.0.0/22
   tcp:30000-32767
   ```
2. Create NodePort type service:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: yourservicenodeport
     labels:
       name: your-service-node-port
   spec:
     type: NodePort
     ports:
       - port: 80
         nodePort: 30001
     selector:
       name: yourpods
   ```
3. Create health check.

   For the nodeport which is in this case: 30001
4. Create an ingress service:

   ```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     name: youTheking-ingress-service
   spec:
     backend:
       serviceName: yourservice
       servicePort: 80
   ```
5. Wait for few minutes, be patient.
6. Change the health check on http load balancer.

   a. Go to the Load Balancing on Networking Tab.

   b. Click Advance menu.

   c. Go Backend Services and Edit.

   d. Update health check option and use the one created for nodeport service.
7. Repeat step 5 for instance group to be recognized health.
8. SSL is needed, go back to the load balancer, edit, click Frontend Configuration, then add https with cert.
9. You are ready to roll.

Comment: Firewall rule and default health check to `nodePort`(30001 in this case), , path `/`are created by GCP, no need to do it.

Comment: Did you have this problem with your load balancer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763718/kubernetes-https-ingress-in-google-container-engine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand you question but I'll try to answer it anyway.

You have two options for exposing your service using a cert signed by a trusted CA:

1. Do what you are doing today but with the real cert. You will probably want to put the cert into a secret and point your nginx configuration at it to load the cert.
2. Replace nginx with the google L7 load balancer. You would upload your certificate to google, configure the L7 balancer to terminate HTTPS and forward traffic to your backends.

Comment: I tried the second option with L7 load balancer. What I couldn't figure out is that on backend service I can include the machines in Container cluster but I cant specify pods that should get the traffic on that cluster. We can configure load balancer service thru kubernetes, I can specify the label for the pod name so that those containers get the traffic

Comment: To connect the L7 balancer with a Kubernetes service, you should expose the service as a `NodePort` service and then configure the L7 service to spread traffic across all machines in your cluster on the port assigned to the service.

Comment: Is there any documentation/example of how to set up l7 with NodePort?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633096/kubernetes-load-balancer-ssl-termination-in-google-container-engine and https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-containers/RyFnp3GGMmQ/z6mdHpLgCwAJ

Comment: It looks like the steps are out of date or I am doing something wrong:( I am having hard time to understand how come we don't have clean instruction to set up such common thing as http(s) balancer in Google cloud for containers