# http -> https redirect in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm looking to redirect all traffic from

http://example.com -> https://example.com like how nearly all websites do.

I've looked at this link with no success:
[Kubernetes HTTPS Ingress in Google Container Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763718/kubernetes-https-ingress-in-google-container-engine)

And have tried the following annotations in my ingress.yaml file.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
```

All without any success. To be clear, I can access https://example.com and  http://example.com without any errors, I need the http call to redirect to https.

Thanks

Comment: How are your services reachable from the internet? Please provide some details re your environment

Comment: Running a django server in Kubernetes Gunicorn, can access it from any ip in the internet. Have an ingress controller/load balancer that has the certs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I ended up using a reverse proxy in NGINX.

1. You need to create secrets and sync them into your containers
2. You need to create a configmap in nginx with your nginx config, as well as a default config that references this additional config file.

Here is my configuration:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

default_type  application/octet-stream;

# Logging Configs
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

# Puntdoctor Proxy Config
include /path/to/config-file.conf;

# PubSub allows 10MB Files. lets allow 11 to give some space
client_max_body_size 11M;

}
```

Then, the config.conf

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

listen 443;
server_name example.com;

ssl_certificate           /certs/tls.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /certs/tls.key;

ssl on;
ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:HIGH:!RC4:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!CAMELLIA;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;

  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://deployment-name:8080/;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;

  proxy_redirect      http://deployment-name:8080/ https://example.com/;
}
}
```

3. Create a deployment:

Here are the .yaml files

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: puntdoctor-lb
spec:
   ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
     - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: puntdoctor-nginx-deployment
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 35.195.214.7
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: puntdoctor-nginx-deployment
spec:
   replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: puntdoctor-nginx-deployment
    spec:
       containers:
       - name: adcelerate-nginx-proxy
        image: nginx:1.13
         volumeMounts:
        - name: certs
          mountPath: /certs/
        - name: site-config
          mountPath: /etc/site-config/
        - name: default-config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
        - containerPort: 443
          name: https
      volumes:
      - name: certs
        secret:
          secretName: nginxsecret
      - name: site-config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
       - name: default-config
        configMap:
         name: default
```

Hope this helps someone solve this issue, thanks for the other 2 answers, they both gave me valuable insight.

Answer (score 6):

GKE uses GCE L7. The rules that you referenced in the example are not supported and the HTTP to HTTPS redirect should be controlled at the application level.

L7 inserts the `x-forwarded-proto` header that you can use to understand if the frontend traffic came using HTTP or HTTPS. Take a look here: [Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/README.md#redirecting-http-to-https)

There is also an example in that link for Nginx (copied for convenience):

```
# Replace '_' with your hostname.
server_name _;
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: At the application level. Do I need to create another NGINX pod? Then handle the redirect at that level. Or can I handle the redirect at the Gunicorn level?

Comment: You can handle the redirect anywhere you want. Probably at the Gunicorn level, but the point is that you'll need to handle it yourself. GCE doesn't support this, yet.

Comment: @DanielLee, as @tex said. Anywhere you want and depends on what you are running, but it is up to you to do so. e.g. I have another pod that runs nodejs and I do it there using `express-sslify`. What is also important is to note the header to know when redirect.

Comment: That example with echoheaders-https / echoserver is nice and it works, but unfortunately it doesn't help if your application isn't based on nginx or apache or similar. In such a case, where/how should one implement https redirection? I have tried to figure that out myself this whole day and can't seem to find an answer...

Comment: @zagrimsan what application are you running?

Comment: @SergeyBahchissaraitsev it is a custom Java application. It's built on Spring framework which actually does seem to allow setting up something like that (haven't tried that out, but did some research on it), but working around infrastructure flaws in the application just seems terribly wrong nonetheless.

Comment: I was able to figure out the solution for my own needs, posted it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750913/2745865

Answer (score 6):

Currently, the documentation for how to do this properly (annotations, SSL/HTTPS, health checks etc) is severely lacking, and has been for far too long. I suspect it's because they prefer you to use the App Engine, which is magical but stupidly expensive. For GKE, here's two options:

- ingress with a google-managed SSL cert and additional NGINX server configuration in front of your app/site
- the NGINX ingress controller with self-managed/third-party SSL certs

The following is steps to a working setup using the former.

## 1 The door to your app

**nginx.conf:** (ellipses represent other non-relevant, non-compulsory settings)

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    ...

    keepalive_timeout  620s;

    ## Logging ##
    ...
    ## MIME Types ##
    ...
    ## Caching ##
    ...
    ## Security Headers ##
    ...
    ## Compression ##
    ....

    server {
        listen 80;

        ## HTTP Redirect ##
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
            return 301 https://[YOUR DOMAIN]$request_uri;
        }

        location /health/liveness {
            access_log off;
            default_type text/plain;
            return 200 'Server is LIVE!';
        }

        location /health/readiness {
            access_log off;
            default_type text/plain;
            return 200 'Server is READY!';
        }

        root /usr/src/app/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name [YOUR DOMAIN] www.[YOUR DOMAIN];

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: **One serving port only**. The global forwarding rule adds the [http_x_forwarded_proto](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#components) header to all traffic that passes through it. Because ALL traffic to your domain is now passing through this rule (remember, one port on the container, service and ingress), this header will (crucially!) always be set. Note the check and redirect above: it only continues with serving if the header value is 'https'. The root and index and location values may differ depending for your project (this is an angular project). keepalive_timeout is set to the value [recommended by google](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#timeouts_and_retries). I prefer using the main nginx.conf file, but most people add a custom.conf file to /etc/nginx/conf.d; if you do this just make sure the file is imported into the main nginx.conf http block using an *includes* statement. The comments highlight where other settings you may want to add when everything is working will go, like gzip/brotli, security headers, where logs are saved, and so on.

**Dockerfile:**

```
...
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

NOTE: only the final two lines. Specifying an EXPOSE port is unnecessary. COPY replaces the default nginx.conf with the modified one. CMD starts a light server.

## 2 Create a deployment manifest and apply/create

**deployment.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: uber-dp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: uber
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: uber
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: uber-ctr
          image: gcr.io/uber/beta:v1 // or some other registry
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            httpGet:
              path: /health/liveness
              port: 80
              scheme: HTTP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            httpGet:
              path: /health/readiness
              port: 80
              scheme: HTTP
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

NOTE: only one specified port is necessary, as we're going to point all (HTTP and HTTPS) traffic to it. For simplicity we're using the same path for liveness and readiness probes; these checks will be dealt with on the NGINX server, but you can and should add checks that probe the health of your app itself (eg a dedicated page that returns a 200 if healthy).The readiness probe will also be picked up by GCE, which by default has its own irremovable health check.

## 3 Create a service manifest and apply/create

**service.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: uber-svc
  labels:
    app: uber
spec:
  ports:
    - name: default-port
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: uber
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

NOTE: default-port specifies port 80 on the container.

## 4 Get a static IP address

On GCP in the hamburger menu: VPC Network -> External IP Addresses. Convert your auto-generated ephemeral IP or create a new one. Take note of the name and address.

## 5 [Create an SSL cert](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates) and default zone

In the hamburger menu: Network Service -> Load Balancing -> click 'advanced menu' -> Certificates -> Create SSL Certificate. Follow the instructions, create or upload a certificate, and take note of the name. Then, from the menu: Cloud DNS -> Create Zone. Following the instructions, [create a default zone](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart) for your domain. Add a CNAME record with www as the DNS name and your domain as the canonical name. Add an A record with an empty DNS name value and your static IP as the IPV4. Save.

## 6 Create an ingress manifest and apply/create

**ingress.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mypt-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: [NAME OF YOUR STATIC IP ADDRESS]
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: [NAME OF YOUR GOOGLE-MANAGED SSL]
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: mypt-svc
    servicePort: 80
```

NOTE: backend property points to the service, which points to the container, which contains your app 'protected' by a server. Annotations connect your app with SSL, and force-allow http for the health checks. Combined, the service and ingress configure the [G7 load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) (combined global forwarding rule, backend and frontend 'services', SSL certs and target proxies etc).

## 7 Make a cup of tea or something

Everything needs ~10 minutes to configure. Clear cache and test your domain with various browsers (Tor, Opera, Safari, IE etc). Everything will serve over https.

**What about the NGINX Ingress Controller?**
I've seen discussion it being better because it's cheaper/uses less resources and is more flexible. It isn't cheaper: it requires an additional deployment/workload and service (GCE L4). And you need to do more configuration. Is it more flexible? Yes. But in taking care of most of the work, the first option gives you a more important kind of flexibility — namely allowing you to get on with more pressing matters.

Answer (score 5):

For everyone like me that searches this question about once a month, Google has responded to our requests and is testing HTTP->HTTPS SSL redirection on their load balancers. [Their latest answer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904733) said it should be in Alpha sometime before the end of January 2020.

Their comment:

> Thank you for your patience on this issue.  The feature is currently in testing and we expect to enter Alpha phase before the end of January.  Our PM team will have an announcement with more details as we get closer to the Alpha launch.

**Update**: HTTP to HTTPS redirect is now Generally Available: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#routing_and_traffic_management

Answer (score 4):

GKE uses its own Ingress Controller which does not support forcing https.

That's why you will have to manage NGINX Ingress Controller yourself.

See [this post](http://rahmonov.me/posts/nginx-ingress-controller/) on how to do it on GKE.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is no more true. Checkout the link: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features

Answer (score 0):

As of GKE version 1.18.10-gke.600, you can use `FrontendConfig` to create `HTTP -> HTTPS redirection` in **Google Kubernetes Engine**

> HTTP to HTTPS redirects are configured using the redirectToHttps field
> in a FrontendConfig custom resource. Redirects are enabled for the
> entire Ingress resource so all services referenced by the Ingress will
> have HTTPS redirects enabled.
>
> The following FrontendConfig manifest enables HTTP to HTTPS redirects.
> Set the spec.redirectToHttps.enabled field to true to enable HTTPS
> redirects. The spec.responseCodeName field is optional. If it's
> omitted a 301 Moved Permanently redirect is used.

For example:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: your-frontend-config-name
spec:
  redirectToHttps:
    enabled: true
    responseCodeName: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
```

`MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT` is on of the available `RESPONSE_CODE` field value, to return a `301` redirect response code (default if `responseCodeName` is unspecified).

You can find more options here: [HTTP to HTTPS redirects](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#https_redirect)

Then you have to link your FrontendConfig to the Ingress, like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: your-ingress-name
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: your-frontend-config-name
spec:
  tls:
    ...
```